# Does Watson NLU support Hebrew?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson, watson-nlu

does Watson NLU support Hebrew, including entities, sentiments? couldnt find it in the documentation

thanks very much
Lior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lior, according to the documentation not. Not yet.

But, I can suggest to you use one Language Translator for using this API with Hebrew and translate to English for using each feature(English has more features available).

In the official documentation has one list of the Supported languages.

The following table shows the supported languages for **each feature**. Natural Language Understanding *automatically detects the language* of your source text by default. You can override automatic language detection if you want to specify the language manually.

**Supported languages:**
[image]

- See the Official reference [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/index.html).
- You can see [this](http://fredrikstenbeck.com/what-languages-does-ibm-watson-support/) article about other's API's and Supported languages. [Last Update: 24th of April 2017]

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't. It is very clear in the documentation.You can find it here.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/language-support.html#language-support

At the time of this post, the compatible languages are:

- Arabic
- Dutch
- English
- French
- German
- Italian
- Japanese
- Korean
- Portuguese
- Russian
- Spanish
- Swedish

Currently, English is the only language that supports all functions provided by Watson NLU. The rest have limited support.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18422751)

Comment: Thank you. I'll change my answer to be more descriptive.